# Using pandas dtype as a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove certain characters from strings within certain columns in a pandas dataframe. I am doing all of this within a for loop so I would like to use an if statement within the loop to perform the actions on all 'object' dtype columns.

```
for col in pitchtype :
pitchtype[col] = pitchtype[col].replace(np.nan,0) 
if pitchtype[col].dtype == 'object':
    pitchtype[col] = pitchtype[col].map(lambda x: x.replace(' %',''))
```

if there a way to make that condition in the if statement?

edit: added my DF below. Basically the columns with % in the header have '%' symbols in the values which are preventing them from being float. I am trying to remove the '%'s and change the columns to type float afterwards.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 264 entries, 0 to 263
```

Data columns (total 18 columns):

```
Name        264 non-null object
Team        264 non-null object
FB%         264 non-null object
FBv         264 non-null float64
SL%         264 non-null object
SLv         264 non-null float64
CT%         264 non-null object
CTv         264 non-null float64
CB%         264 non-null object
CBv         264 non-null float64
CH%         264 non-null object
CHv         264 non-null float64
SF%         264 non-null object
SFv         264 non-null float64
KN%         264 non-null object
KNv         264 non-null float64
XX%         264 non-null object
playerid    264 non-null int64

dtypes: float64(7), int64(1), object(10)
memory usage: 37.2+ KB
```

Comment: Can you share your DF and expected output?

Comment: Added the DF. I have the IF statement but it's not picking up or compiling correctly since columns with other dtypes are getting passed through. I get the following error:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: You don't need quote around the `object`, because otherwise it's not a dtype, but rather a string that says `'object'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this maybe what you're looking for, checking individual object to see if they're string.

```
if pitchtype[col].dtype == object: # No quotes around it!
    pitchtype[col] = pitchtype[col].map(lambda x: x.replace(' %','') if type(x) == str else x)
```

Comment: oh perfect! this worked. Is it redundant though for me to have both dtype == object and if type(x) == str though? I always assumed that object type was some sort of string

Comment: @Eric In case you did `memory_low=False` in loading a column can actually have different dtypes. But in this case there's the other check you can do: `if "%" in x else` in the lambda to make sure you're removing the string which has `'%'` in it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and [`pd.Series.str.rstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
for col in df.select_dtypes(['object']):
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col].str.rstrip('%'), errors='coerce')
```

The conversion to `float` is performed by [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html). `errors='coerce'` gives `NaN` for non-convertible values.